# Como agir com perguntas que pedem contato por e-mail, telefone, etc.?

Tags: debate

Agora pouco me deparei com [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157748/18246), onde o AP colocou o seu Skype Id e pediu que adicionássemos ele para ajudá-lo com o problema em questão porque ele não poderia "ficar acessando o site".

Ao meu ver, num primeiro momento, este não é o objetivo do site e o Skype Id dele é completamente irrelevante, assim como os cumprimentos e agradecimentos no início e fim das publicações, tanto que eu tomei a liberdade de editar a publicação e remover esta informação.

Acontece que eu fiquei intrigado e não sei se agi certo. Como deveríamos agir nestes casos?

Comment: Jovem, temos o chat do site. Usamos ele para zoar e trocar altas ideias, mas creio que um bom uso dele seria ajudando alguns usuários (inclusive acabei de citar isso numa resposta minha)

Comment: [O que fazer quando um usuário solicita contato via e-mail?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/733/91)

Comment: Geralmente, quando o usuário pede contato, tem grande chance de se tratar de um problema tão específico, que não ajudaria ninguém (e sabemos que o site tem algumas perguntas assim).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu sei que tem o chat, mas o AP não tem reputação pra acessá-lo.

Comment: @rray valeu! Você é demais.

Comment: Quando "comenta demais", acho que ele pode acessar.

Comment: @jbueno Você sempre pode abrir um chat sobre a questão específica onde o AP pode participar. Como dito pelo Wallace, basta "comentar muito" que o sistema sugere essa opção.

Comment: Ótimo! Não sabia disso, valeu @Randrade e Wallace

Comment: @jbueno que é dup da mostrada pelo rray?

Comment: Não entendi, @bigown. Você se refere ao comentário que eu disse que "não sabia 'disso'"?

Comment: Digo, ao fato desta pergunta ser duplicata da outra e já responder oque deseja. Mas vi que considera sim :)

Comment: Isso. Eu considero duplicada sim, eu quis dizer no comentário acima (onde agradeci os colegas) que desconhecia o recurso de permitir o usuário entrar numa sala de chat quando o sistema sugerisse isto pelo excesso de comentários.